# Mysql is throwing an error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1093

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM mytable where roll=1)
```

I have a table `mytable`. My above query is throwing an error.

You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

> Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Fortunately, you don't need the subquery. Just do:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE roll=1
```

It's much shorter and clearer to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this?

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE roll=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE roll=1
```

?
The error occurs because MySql doesn't like it to fetch form a table in a subquery when the superior query modifies the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE roll=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using subquery? You can write it this way:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE where roll=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Errors/1093-You-can-not-specify-target-table-comments-for-update-in-FROM-clause) explains why you can't do this.

And in this example, you can just use:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE roll=1
```